# Torque of a compound pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque

Let us consider a compound pendulum with the mass $m$ which moves along the $xy$-plane and rotates about the $z$-axis. Its pivot is at $(0, 0, 0)$, and the vector from the pivot to the centre of mass is $\vec{l} = (l_x, l_y, 0)$. The force acting on the pendulum is $\vec{F}=m\vec{g}=(0, -mg, 0)$. I calculated the torque by taking the cross product:

$$\vec{\tau}= (l_x, l_y, 0) \ \times \ (0, -mg, 0) = (0, 0, -mgl_x)$$

It is a reasonable result because the torque is parallel to the $z$-axis, and the direction is well-considered. However, this is often expressed with its common form: $-mgl \sin \theta$.

I would happily accept this if $\theta$ starts from the positive $x$-axis direction. But $\theta$ here is the angle between $\vec{l}$ and $m\vec{g}$, so it obviously does not start from the positive $x$-axis direction.

I think I am challenged with trigonometric concepts. Please tell me how to do the calculation here appropriately. I wonder whether separate triangles should be drawn to calculate the sine. Also, if I do so, there will be so many absolute value signs which are quite hard to deal with.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a diagram for this question!!!

Comment: Draw a diagram! $\theta$ is measured from the vertical. Then $\ell_x=\ell\sin\theta$.

Comment: What is your difficulty? Doesn't my comment resolve it for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the red triangle below, the offset from vertical is clearly $\ell \sin \theta$

[image: pic]

But, if you are asking about angle sense convention that is compatible with the right-hand rule (and the cross product) then positive angles need to be counter-clockwise.

The *positive* $\theta$ angle is thus

[image: pic2]

with $ \ell \sin \theta $ being negative for angles larger than 180° (as shown).

Comment: The problem is the diagram is drawn with a negative angle. Angles are supposed to be counter-clockwise positive, and $\theta$ is measured from the vertical. This convention is compatible with the cross product. As drawn the angle is not compatible with the cross product. Flip the drawing about the _y_-axis and try again.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your explanation is convincing. I have one question. Is it ok if I set the y-axis (in between 3rd and 4th quadrants) where $\theta=0$ and then (according to the coordinate system which I use) set a negative angle for the 3rd quadrant and a positive for the 4th?

Comment: You are free to set angle=0 anywhere you want. But designate (+) as CCW for both angles and torques. The key is to be _consistent_ in your convention for positive directions and rotational sense.